# If you can't nest HTML forms, how can you submit multiple selections?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

So for example, I have a table with a checkbox for each row. Now, I added in the functionality to be able to delete multiple selected rows by using built in rails form helper. The problem is, I also need to be able to 'disable selected' and 'enable selected' rows as well.

```
 <%= form_tag sccm_destroy_multiple_url , method: :delete do %>
 .... some table rows and data
 <%= check_box_tag "ID[]", group.id %>
 ... some more rows

<%= button_tag "Delete Selected", type: 'button submit', class: "btn btn-danger",data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete these groups?"} do %>                          

<i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete Selected
<%end%>
<%end%>
```

Now I need to put another button  to "Disable Selected" but I can't do this since it would be nesting forms and forms are the only way to store multiple checkbox IDs that I'm aware of...any ideas?

Comment: you can submit as many/few form field key=name pairs as you want. there may be limits set in the browser and/or server as to how many they'll send/accept, but usually that's a pretty high limit.

Comment: the problem is, each submit button needs to map to a different route, since each functionality maps to a different controller action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically rails gets around this limitation in HTML by creating arrays and nested hashes from the name attributes:

```
<input type="text" name="dogs[0][breed]" value="Husky">
<input type="text" name="dogs[1][breed]" value="Shiba Inu">
```

rails will interpret these params as:

```
"dogs" => {
  "0" => {
    "breed" => "Husky"
  },
  "1" => {
    "breed" => "Shiba Inu"
  },
}
```

You would normally use [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) which gives you a special "scoped" form builder instance:

```
<%= forms_for(@adaption_agency) do |k| %>
   <%= f.fields_for(:dogs) do |doggy_fields| %>
     <%= doggy_fields.text_field :breed %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In your case what you could create an `update_multiple` route and use fields_for with an array of records.

But I would consider using ajax instead to allow the user to manipulate several records on the same page with just the standard CRUD actions. It is a lot less complex than trying to mosh everything into mega actions.

```
<%= dogs.each do |doggy| %>
   <%= form_for(doggy), class: 'doggy-form' do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_input :breed %>
   <% end %>
   <%= button_to('Delete', dog_path(doggy), method: :delete, class: 'doggy-form') %>
<% end %>
```

Note that this creates forms for each type of action.